# AngularJS: Cookies disappear when I route to other page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I created a feature like a shopping cart using AngularS, when I route to Items page and add new items it works perfectly, I use cookies to persist these items temporarily, but with the items in the cart if I route to another page that is not the same as the one I used to add to the cart the cart cookie variable disappears, and because I initialize the cart cookie to an empty array if it does not exist the count of my cart items become zero. Below are the codes I used.

Cart.js: Bootstraps the Cart application

```
var app = angular.module('cartApp', ['Resly.CartRepositories', 'Resly.CartControllers']);

 app.run(function($rootScope, $cookieStore){
     $rootScope.cart =  $cookieStore.get('cart') || [];
 });
```

CartControllers.js: Handles user actions/interactions from the view

```
var cartControllers = angular.module('Resly.CartControllers', ['ngCookies']);

cartControllers.controller('CartController', function($rootScope, $http ){
    this.addTable = function(tableID){
        var callbackHandler = RestaurantRepository.getTableByID(tableID);
        callbackHandler.then(function successFul(response){
            $rootScope.cart = response.data;
            $cookieStore.put('cart', $rootScope.cart);
            // console.log($cookieStore.get('cart'));

        }, function failure(){
            // console.log('error');
        });
    };
});
```

CartRepository.js: Handles making API calls to backend

```
var RestaurantRepositories = angular.module('Resly.CartRepositories', []);
RestaurantRepositories.service('RestaurantRepository', function($http){
    var restaurant = this;
    restaurant.getTableByID = function(tableID){
        return $http.get('/tables/'+tableID+'/get.json');
    };
    return restaurant;
});
```

On the view I have a button

```
<body ng-app='cartApp'>
    <div ng-controller='CartController as cartCtrl'>
       <button ng-click='cartCtrl.addTable(13)'>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please I need help figuring why the data keeps disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the variable $cookieStore in your controller and your service, like this:

cartControllers.controller('CartController', function($rootScope, $http,RestaurantRepository,$cookieStore ){
...
});

With your example you are not adding the variable to the cookies, then when you change the view continue getting your empty cart from the cookies.